# How can I use two labels inside one prototype cell in a TableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "my string"
```

This above works fine but I would like to have two different textLabels like I do in my prototype cell.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit
cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = holesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        cell.labelHole?.text = "Hole \(mainCurrentHoleNumber)"

        cell.labelShots?.text = "\(mainShotsEachHole[indexPath.row])"

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: How are you registering your prototype cell?

Comment: holesTableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

Comment: What's the type of the cell that you get in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = holesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        
        cell.labelHole?.text = "Hole \(mainCurrentHoleNumber)"
        
        cell.labelShots?.text = "\(mainShotsEachHole[indexPath.row])"
        
        return cell
    }`
The "labelHoles" and "labelShots" don't appear :( It only works when I replace them with textLabel but then only one of them shows up

Comment: And that's not working right?

Comment: Register the nib, not the cell.

    (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

Comment: The code came out so ugly so I just added it to the main post above.
But yeah, When I do it like that with my custom labels nothing appears in the TableView.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if your are using storyboard to create your cell, just drag and drop another label and then make a custom UITableViewCell class for that prototype cell and click hold and drag while holding control to make outlets for the labels. After you make outlets you can use both textLabels in your code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel2: UILabel!
```

Either hold control and click and drag using the assistant editor to make the outlet or type the above line in your custom cell class and then right click on the left pane (storyboard scene) in the storyboard and connect the outlet you make to the label.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! 
I already have two labels linked but it seems like I cant use anything other than the exact variable "textLabel" when adding text to a cell.

Comment: So you have two labels and they both have different variable names and the are linked to your storyboard. Can you send a screenshot of your custom cell class and where you are trying to add text? I don't understand why you can't use the other label.

Comment: Ohhh I understand. You need to use the variable name you made in the outlet like cell.myLabel.text = "My string". You should also check the class of the prototype cell in the storyboard to see if it matches the custom cell class

Answer (score 0):

1. Register the nib, not the cell.

   (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

Comment: let nib = UINib(nibName: REUSABLE, bundle: Bundle.main)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: REUSABLE)